# Displaying categories with different colors on 3D scatter plot

Tags: matlab

Along with 3 numeric values the data contains categorical value (0 or 1) and would like to display the data using 3D scatter plot. I have tried to write a function to read the data from csv file and create a scatter plot the following way:

```
function f = ScatterPlotUsers(filename)

    data = ReadCSV(filename);
    x = data(:,2);
    y = data(:,3);
    z = data(:,4);

    size = ones(length(x), 1)*20;
    userType = data(:,5);
    colors = zeros(length(x), 1);

    a = find(userType == 1);
    b = find(userType == 0);
    colors(a,1) = 42; %# color for users type a
    colors(b,1) = 2;  %# color for users type b

    scatter3(x(:),y(:),z(:),size, colors,'filled') 
    view(-60,60);
```

What I actually wanted to do was to set the colour for a to red and b to blue but no matter the colour values (42 and 2 in example) the colours of dots don't change.
Does anyone know what is the right way to determine specific colours for several categorical values (in this case only 0 and 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it right, however, are you sure the colormap entries 42 and 2 refer to red and blue? You could try to give RGB values explicitly:

```
colors = zeros(length(x), 3);
colors(userType == 1, :) = [1 0 0]; %# colour for users type a (red)
colors(userType == 2, :) = [0 0 1]; %# colour for users type b (blue)
```

Also, I'd advise you to change the name of the variable `size`, since `size` is also a Matlab command; Matlab might be confused about that, and any future readers of your code will *certainly* be confused about that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use colormap, especially if your `userType` values start at 0 and increase:

```
% Read in x, y, z, and userType.

userType = userType + 1;

colormap(lines(max(userType)));

scatter3(x, y, z, 20, userType);
```

If you want specific colors, replace `lines(...)` with a matrix. For example, if you had 3 user types and you wanted them red, green, and blue:

```
colormap([1, 0, 0;
          0, 1, 0;
          0, 0, 1]);
```

A few other notes:

We add one to `userType` to switch from 0-based indexing to 1-based indexing.

You can use a scalar for the `size` parameters of scatter3 instead of specifying an array of a single value.